# Paytm Payment Gateway integration in Android app without current account

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paytm

I am developing an Android app for an event in my college and I want to accept registration amount through an online payment system. The problem is we have a savings account not a current account. I am thinking maybe I could just simply transfer the amount from the participant's paytm wallet to my(or any other preferred) paytm wallet, if this is possible how to implement this?

I would also like to know how to generate links using paytm APIs to accept payment in my paytm wallet, and how to visit the link in a webview and retrieve the result of the transaction through the webview.
Otherwise, I am looking for a payment gateway which will allow me to accept payments into my savings account.

I have gone through all this :

[Paytm SDK](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit)

[Paytm APIs](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc/)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you face any problem understanding the SDK? What is your actual question?

Comment: I think I understand how to use the SDK, but as I mentioned in the question we have a savings account(paytm needs a current account), so since we cannot use the gateway can you suggest some solution to accept online payments with in our android app?